having error while inserting image
while applying this code, my output for image i have inserted is mixed pixels like blurry image is showing. Please help

\documentclass[a4,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[a4paper, inner=1.5cm, outer=3cm, top=2cm,
bottom=3cm, bindingoffset=0.5cm]{geometry}
\title{VAC Assignment}
\author{Prashant Yadav (22/6204)}
\date{\today}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\include{Forward}
\include{Rationalisation of the contents in the textbooks}
\include{Textbook Development Committee}
\include{Acknowledgement}
\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
    \includegraphics[scale=1]{preamble.jpg}
\end{figure}
\end{document}


you have not provided any information that could help debug this.  we can not run the code shown as it \include  files we do not have (they are presumably not related so you should remove them from  the example) but there does not look anything wrong with the tex code so probably there is a problem with the image that we don't have and can't debug

Hello! the image may be too bigger, and you are using scale=1. Try decreasing the scale.

Your image just might be very large in size. As a remedy, try a reasonable "auto scaling" of the image with, e.g., using \inludegraphics[width=\textwidth]{...}. Then you should at least be able to see the whole image and could check if something went wrong with the image itself.

Safer would be [width=\textwidth, height=\textheight, keepaspectratio], but only with a [p] or [ht!] figure.
